# Arduino code for a button and a led

Tags: arduino

I have a question.
In my code (Arduino), the led is high as long as I push on a button.

```
int led=12;
int button=4;

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  pinMode(led,OUTPUT);//tekst
  pinMode(button,INPUT_PULLUP);
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:


    if(digitalRead(button))
    {
      digitalWrite(led,HIGH);
    }

   else 
   {
      digitalWrite(led,LOW);
   }
}
```

But I want the next one: If I push on a button the first time =>the led is high

```
                     if I push a second time=> the led is low
                     if I push a third time => the led is high

                     etc.
```

Is there anyone that can help me?
Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you have thought much about your problem.

Just form a sentence of what you want to do:

I want to turn on the led when I push the button  and the led is off.
I want to turn off the led when I push the button and the led is on.

Now some pseudocode:

```
if the button pin is HIGH:
  if the led pin is HIGH:
    put the led pin LOW
  else
    put the led pin HIGH
```

I'll leave it up to you to translate it into C++.

Please make your self familiar with "debouncing" of buttons. Otherwise you might run into weird behaviour.

Comment: +1 on your answer. Just to add, there's an example already built into the Arduino IDE called Debounce which does exactly what OP is looking for. I suggest OP look through the examples and get familiar with these small concepts.